# Replacing lines in one file by keys in another file-python

Tags: python

I have been trying to replace lines in file1.txt by keys in another file2.txt. I have two text files in the following formats:

file1.txt

```
       SNP_A-43344   rs176444
       SNP_A-53343   rs2345
       SNP_A-57574   rs89902222
          .          .
          .          .
          .          .
       SNP_A-47474    rs474784
          .          .
          .          .
          .          .
```

and file2.txt

```
  rs176444
  rs89902222
  rs474784
    .
    .
    .
```

I want to replace the contents of file2.txt with their SNP numbers so that file2.txt looks like this:

```
        SNP_A-43344 
        SNP_A-57574
        SNP_A-47474 
            .
            .
            .
```

I have seen some examples online but I cannot figure it out. I have been altering the code below for many hours now but I am just changing the entries in my original files.

```
       import re
       with open('file1.txt','r') as f:
            data1=dict(line.split() for line in f)
       with open('file2.txt') as f:
            data2=f.read()
       data2=re.sub(pattern,SNPnumber,data2)
```

I have been playing around with the pattern and SNPnumber entries in re.sub. Is this the correct approach or am I doing this completely wrong. I am new to python and I would appreciate if you could give me some suggestions or direct me to a source. Thanks!

Comment: is SNP- number is unique in file1.txt??

Comment: Yes the SNP numbers are unique

Comment: is rs.... is also unique???

Comment: Yes, rs numbers are also unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
my_dict = {}
with open("file1.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        value, key = line.strip().split()    # taking rs... as key and SNP-.. as value
        my_dict[key] = value

rs_values = open("file2.txt").readlines()

with open("file2.txt", "w") as f:
    for x in rs_values:
        f.write(my_dict[x.strip()] + "\n")
```

Comment: I got an error :                                                                                   f.write(my_dict[x] + "\n")
KeyError: 'SNP_A-1819635\trs17642438\n'

Comment: can you print the content of my_dict and see key value pair

Comment: yeah. I get entries like 'SNP_A-1987912', 'rs911114': 'SNP_A-2226006', 'rs458744': 'SNP_A-8341206', etc...

Comment: I apologize. The code does work. I was inputing the wrong file. Thank you!